# firebase-admin adding a random alphanumeric key to the realtime database when using push()

Tags: python, django, firebase, django-rest-framework, firebase-admin

I am using the Python `firebase-admin` library to integrate Django rest framework and Firebase Realtime storage. I am using the `push()` function to create a new child node. However, the function adds an alphanumeric key to each child. Is there a way I can avoid that and add my own custom keys to the data?

See example below:

```py
    def post(self, request):
        """Function to handle post requests

        Args:
            request (_type_): _description_
        """

        # Get the data to be posted from the request 
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        age = request.POST.get('age')
        location = request.POST.get('location')

        # Set the reference to the database
        ref = db.reference('/')

        # Push the data to the database
        ref.push({"user1" : {
            'Name': name,
            'Age': age,
            'Location': location
        }})

        return JsonResponse({"message": "Data posted successfully"}, status=200)
```

When I run this, the node is created as follows

```json
{
    "data": {
        "-NNzIPh4SUHo6FLhs060": {
            "user1": {
                "Age": "20",
                "Location": "US",
                "Name": "Dummy name 2"
            }
        },
        "user2": {
            "Age": "22",
            "Location": "count1",
            "Name": "Dummy 1"
        }
    }
}
```

The `-NNzIPh4SUHo6FLhs060` key is created which I want to customize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `push()` is an instruction to the database to generate a new unique child node for the data that you pass. If you want to write the data directly at the path you specify, use `set()` instead of `push()`.

Also see the Firebase documentation on [saving data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-set)

Comment: This link explains it well. Thanks a lot!